# Running Spring Boot application in embedded Tomcat server in Linux

Tags: linux, spring-boot, tomcat7

I am running Spring Boot application in embedded Tomcat server. I am placing the executable jar file with Tomcat server embedded in it in a path in Linux server, logging in to Linux environment using putty, navigating to the path where I have kept my jar file and running as

```
java -jar my-jar.jar
```

The problem is using this way the embedded tomcat server will stop and the jar file will stop running when putty is exited. Can you suggest a way how to execute the executable jar file so that it keeps running in the Linux environment without stopping.

One solution I found is to run the jar as a service of Linux. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start it as background process:

```
java -jar my-jar.jar &
```

But the Linux service is the better way.